# Why does one specific customer's IP get refused (403 error) from our apache2.4?

Tags: apache, ubuntu

We never had any problem and we didn't deploy anything, but one particular customer on his ipv6 addr is now getting 403 error from our Apache and I just can't figure out why.

I'm not sure what to provide but I double check every a2 config file.

I can see the customer access in the access.log (with the 403 code status), but nothing in the error.log.

access.log :

```
2a02:2788(...):102f - - [17/May/2021:12:54:12 +0200] "GET /page_url HTTP/1.0" 403 368 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36 Edg/89.0.774.75"
2a02:2788(...):102f - - [17/May/2021:12:54:15 +0200] "GET /page_url HTTP/1.0" 403 368 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36 Edg/89.0.774.75"
```

It's not on the application level too, we don"t have anything that return a 403 error.

Any idea on what Apache can do to trigger 403 error specificly on IP ?

Comment: What makes you think this is related to the "specific IP"? What is the significance of "Ubuntu"? Are you hosting this yourself? Do you have full control of the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why/how is the customer seemingly making an `HTTP/1.0` request? This alone *could* be sufficient reason for the server to reject the request since normal users using normal browsers don't send HTTP 1.0 requests. (`HTTP/1.1` is expected.)

Generally, only certain bots make HTTP 1.0 requests.

An Apache module like mod_security could potentially have a rule that would block such requests. (Or any other rule using mod_rewrite, for instance, could also block such requests - but this is certainly not a default.)

> ```
>  Edg/89.0.774.75
> ```

It would seem this may have been a *bug* with Microsoft Edge, as the following Microsoft community post (from around the same time as this question) would seem to suggest:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/all/internet-explorer-and-ms-edge-sends-ssl-requests/22708bcd-f196-45fb-84c9-6d8c34e7e08f

And as also noted in the above article, this would seem to have been "fixed" in later versions. So, your customer may also now be "fixed". (?)